# PHP convert XML file with multiple records to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, xml, laravel-5

I want to convert a big XML file (size 19 MB) with multiple records in a JSON.

First, I am new in handling XML data.

I have this code in PHP (Laravel framework):

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
echo json_encode((object) array('productId' => $doc->Products->Product->ProductId, 'price' => $doc->Products->Product->Price));
```

But echo returns only first record:

```
{"productId":{"0":"C6900015 "},"price":{"0":"140.5100"}}
```

I want to convert all the records of this type in a JSON.

Afert I made this, I want to use this JSON as a source for [yajra DataTables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) or send to MySQL table (insert or update).

I don't know how to count all the records and send to JSON in a 'while' or 'foreach' loop.

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");

foreach ($doc->Products->Product as $product) {
    // echo $product->ProductId . ', ' . $product->Price . '<br>';
    echo json_encode((object) array('productId' => $product->ProductId, 'price' => $product->Price));
}
```